# awk + one line awk syntax to print only once the second field if "true" word matched

Tags: awk

I don't know how to do this with awk
But my target is to create awk one line syntax in order to print the second field ($2) if 
all first field ($1) are true

for example

I have the file:

```
   true my_name_is_lenon
   true my_name_is_lenon
   true my_name_is_lenon
   false my_name_is_lenon
   true my_name_is_lenon

   false my_dog_is_fat
   true my_dog_is_fat
   true my_dog_is_fat

   true I_am_very_tall
   true I_am_very_tall
   true I_am_very_tall

   true my_ball_is_fine
   true my_ball_is_fine
```

the awk will print only the following:

```
 I_am_very_tall
 my_ball_is_fine
```

Because I_am_very_tall , my_ball_is_fine get true on the first field without false

my_dog_is_fat , my_name_is_lenon not printed because the false word on the first field

The rule is to print the second field if no false word on the first field! (Of all the same sentence on the second field)

lidia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "false") {array[$2] = $1} else if (array[$2] != "false") array[$2] = $1} END {for (i in array) if (array[i] == "true") print i}' inputfile
```

**Edit:**

Here it is on multiple lines:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "false") 
         {array[$2] = $1} 
     else if (array[$2] != "false") 
         array[$2] = $1} 
     END {for (i in array)
             if (array[i] == "true") 
                 print i}
' inputfile
```

Comment: hi dennis
can you change the awk like radoulov awk? (not one line)
THX
lidia

Comment: @lidia: OK, but your question said "awk one line syntax".

Comment: I think its better not one line (in the script its not look fine)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each block is of the same category.

```
$ awk -vRS= '!/false/' file | uniq | awk '{print $NF}'
I_am_very_tall
my_ball_is_fine
```

Comment: sorry but this awk not work try the follwoing file :     
   true my_name_is_lenon 
   true my_name_is_lenon 
   true my_name_is_lenon 
   false my_name_is_lenon 
   true my_name_is_lenon 
 
   false my_dog_is_fat 
   true my_dog_is_fat 
   true my_dog_is_fat 
 
   true I_am_very_tall 
   true I_am_very_tall 
   true I_am_very_tall 
 
   true my_ball_is_fine 
   true my_ball_is_fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible as an awk one-liner. At least not easily. Is awk absolutely required? As there are one line shell solutions available if awk is just part of the solution.

For example, this is a shell one-liner (just a long line):

```
awk '{ print $2 }' < {infile} | while read line; do grep -i "false $line" {infile} > /dev/null || echo $line; done | uniq
```

It's not efficient, but it does do the job.

In comparison, the shortest awk solution I've got is about 25 lines (which I can drop here in here if you want -- leave a comment and I'll update this accordingly). But this would then mean you could save this to a file and execute `awk -f alltrue.awk < {infile}`. I'm not sure this strictly classes as a perl one-liner though :-)

A better understanding of what you're ultimately trying to achieve or what this is for might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

And another one:

```
awk 'END { 
  for (A in all)  
    if (!(A in ko)) print A
  }
NF { all[$2] } 
$1 == "false" { ko[$2] }
' infile
```

If you want to preserve the original order, you'll need more code though.

Answer (score 0):

Another compact solution.

```
awk '
  $1 == "true" && ! ($2 in false) {true[$2]}
  $1 == "false" {false[$2]; delete true[$2]}
  END {for (word in true) print word}
' true.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
gawk '{a[$2]=a[$2] || $1=="false"} END {for (i in a) if (!a[i] && i) print i}' a.txt

my_ball_is_fine
I_am_very_tall
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
awk '{$1=="false" ? false[$2]="false" : true[$2]="true"} END{for (i in true) if   (!false[i]) {print i} }'
```

my_ball_is_fine
I_am_very_tall